# Date Time column conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I am running `Except` query in SQL Server to match data between the Source and the Target. In source column `LastDate` (datatype: `Date`) but in the target a column `LastDate` is divided into three parts as Last Date (DataType:timestamp), LastDate Date (Datatype :DATE) and Last Date Time(Datatype :Time).

Can you provide me with syntax to resolve this issue?

The Source is Oracle and the Target is Teradata. Thanks in advance.

This is my query:

```
Select 
    Name, Age, Lastdate 
from 
    TableA@oracle 

except 

Select 
    Name, Age, Lastdate 
from 
    TableA@Teradata
```

Comment: But Lastdate in Terdata is divided into 3 col                         Last Date (DataType:timestamp)                                  LastDate Date (Datatype :DATE) and Last Date Time(Datatype :Time).

Comment: Teradata's TIMESTAMP is the same as Oracle's DATE, there's no need to combine separate date/time columns.

Comment: columns all already separated and i need to test the tables to verify the dates from source matches target.There are like 500 tables .Thanks

Comment: You wrote you got three columns in Teradata, timestamp/date/time, so simply use the timestamp.

Comment: can you provide me with query as target as 3 extra col compare to source .How would i run except query

Comment: I assume that the date + time column has the same value as the timestamp column (of course this is redundant). So simply don't add the date/time columns to the select.

Comment: yeas but i need to verify that date ,time is same in both target and source